# Is tracking tasks in a static dictionary and awaiting tasks initiated in a separate request thread-safe?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, task-management

In a .NET Core asp.net web application I'm building, tasks are initiated in a request; in certain scenarios, we want to await the completion of this task in another request.

To accomplish this, I've put in place a static dictionary that stores references to these tasks:

```
 public static volatile Dictionary<int, Task> MyTasks = new Dictionary<int, Task>();
```

Running tasks are awaited, if necessary, from separate requests:

```
 public static async Task GenerateMyData(int itemId, SomeOtherData data)
 {
     var curTask = MyTasks.Get(itemId); //<- extension method wrapper for TryGetValue
     if (curTask != null && !curTask.IsCompleted)
     {
         await curTask;
     }

     var newTask = Task.Run(async () =>
     {
          AddPrimaryData(itemId, data);
          await AddImageData(itemId, data);
          MyTasks[itemId] = null;
     });

     MyTasks[itemId] = newTask;

}
```

While it works in my development environment and as web-app under a light load, the more I read about async/await the more unsure I am if this will function as expected under a heavier load.  Does this method appear to be safe for an asp.net core 2.1 web app?

Comment: A dictionary is not thread-safe, you need to either switch to a thread safe data structure, or synchronize all access to it.

Comment: Also, if you are on a farm, a different server can be handling the other request.

Comment: Not on a server farm but great point, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use the thread-safe [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8). Making a classic collection `volatile` alone doesn't make it thread-safe. You would have to enclose all the operations in a `lock` statement.

You add items with (`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> Class`)

```
bool success = dict.TryAdd(itemId, data);
```

And retrieve them with

```
bool success = dict.TryGetValue(itemId, out data);
```

There are also methods like `TryRemove` and `TryUpdate`.

Comment: Be aware that `TryGetValue` leaves the item in the collection, where another thread could find it. It would still work (a `Task` can be awaited more than once, and each time it will get the same value), but I'm not sure that's what you want. If it should only ever be found once, then use [`TryRemove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove), which will return the value and remove it from the collection.